# CorePlot: How can I add title on plots for ScatterPlot

Tags: objective-c, core-plot, title

I'm using `CorePlot` library and I would like to add a title for each plot in `CPTScatterPlot`.
Why `plot.title = @"TITLE"` doesn't work!

```
CPTScatterPlot *plot = [[[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init] autorelease];

plot.dataSource = self;
plot.identifier = @"IDENTIFIER";
plot.dataLineStyle = dataLineStyle;
plot.plotSymbol = plotSymbol;
plot.title = @"TITLE";

[self.graph addPlot:plot];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `title` of a plot is the name displayed in the legend. Add a legend to your graph and the title will appear. You can add a title to the graph itself.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't solve my problem! I have several plots in a graph and I can't add a title manually, in addition to I allow to user for zoom in/out graph! So can you guide me for using 'legend' in my `ScatterPlot` without using `UIImageView`?

Comment: There are several examples of legends in the Plot Gallery example app. You can also use an annotation to place a label at an arbitrary position on the graph.

Comment: By the way, not directly but your advice works for me! Thank you!